# How to find if a string starts with one of several options in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to find out if a string starts with one of several different options. For example, I want to know if a string starts with any vowel ("a" or "e" or "i" or "u").

I believe I should be using Clojure's `starts-with?`, but I don't know where to go from there. I have tried using a regular expression but couldn't get that right. I also tried using `(or "a" "e" "i" "o" "u")` but that also wasn't right.

---

EDIT: after more experimentation it seems that
`(re-matches #"^[aeiou].*" string)`
works, but I don't know if that's the best way to do it

Comment: Now I'm wondering whether instead of `starts-with?` I should be using a regex that only matches the start of a string -- will work on figuring that option out as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex is fine. Without regex:

```
(contains? (set "aeiou") (first "apple"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `starts-with?`, you'd need to iterate the list of vowels. I'd use `some` for helping with this since you just care if *some* vowel is contained at the start of the string:

```
(some #(s/starts-with? "hello" (str %)) "aeiou")
=> nil

(some #(s/starts-with? "apple" (str %)) "aeiou")
=> true
```

Honestly though, I'd just do what @Michiel has already suggested and do a set lookup, although I'd do it a little differently:

```
(-> "apple"
    (first) ; Is the first letter
    #{\a \e \i \o \u}) ; In the set of vowels?
=> \a ; Truthy!

(-> "hello"
    (first)
    #{\a \e \i \o \u})
=> nil
```

Comment: Depends if you want a boolean result.

Comment: @MichielBorkent In nearly every context I've ever been in, a truthy value is sufficient. And this answer was more to show how it might be done using `starts-with?`, since they mention it in the question. The second part is just a tag on.